# Issue while copying a file from remote server to local server

Tags: php, ssh, ssh2

I'm trying to copy a few dynamic files from a remote server to a local server using PHP ssh2_connect.
Below is the code :

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('XXX.XXX.XX.x', 8288);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'abcd');
ssh2_scp_recv($connection, $absolute_remote_file_name, $absolute_local_path);
```

Below are the errors coming:

```
ssh2_scp_recv(absolute_local_path) : failed to open stream: Is a directory in
ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to write to local file in
```

How can I overcome these errors and make it possible to copy/tranfer files from remote to local server.

Comment: What is the value of $absolute_local_path?  I suggest you first ensure that it is correct and references a location your script has permission to write to.

Update: from your error message, it looks like you are referencing a directory and not a file.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Although not an answer, [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp) is a really awesome library that wraps things like SSH and SFTP and (IMHO) makes it so much easier to work with. The 3.0 dropped support for SCP in favor of SFTP, but the 2.0 is still out there with that if you can't use SFTP.

Comment: Rob eyre $absolute_local_path is the path where I want file from remote server to be transferred. Script is running as root. Please suggest what permission should I give to the destination directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been identified and its in the below mentioned block of code.

```
ssh2_scp_recv($connection, $absolute_remote_file_name, $absolute_local_path);
```

We were mentioning destination as directory and assuming file from source(what so ever is the name of the file) will automatically transferred to destination directory with same name as source file name.
But instead of giving $absolute_local_path(/var/temp/transferred/file/) we have to give exact name which we want so instead of $absolute_local_path we have to mention name of destination file(/var/temp/transferred/file/t1.csv).